# Parsing NSString to get data out

Tags: cocoa, parsing, nsstring

I have this code...

```
NSData* myData = producedData;
NSLog(@"Contents of myData: %@", myData);
```

The log prints

{
    "id" = "";
    "level" = "level_1";
    "handle" = test;
}

How do I get the values for id and level and handle out of this? The original data is a NSString*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it JSON? Use Stig Brautaset's JSON parser http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Comment: JSON uses colons, not equal signs.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the code that actually obtains the data object, nor are you showing any code related to an NSString.

Are you just assigning a string (`producedData`) to your `myData` variable? That won't create a data object; for one thing, it wouldn't know what encoding to use to encode the string's characters into bytes, and more importantly, copying a pointer from one variable to another (which is what `myData = producedData` does—the variables do not contain the objects themselves, only pointers to them) does not change anything about what the pointer points to. The object will remain a string, even though you told the compiler that `myData` would point to a data object. The compiler should be warning you about this; you should heed and fix those warnings.

`myData` definitely is not a data object; if it were, its description of itself would be a hex dump. It is either a string or a dictionary.

The output you showed matches the syntax that an NSDictionary uses to describe itself. On the other hand, the object could be a string containing such a description. (This latter case is what you're expecting.)

If you have a dictionary: You're done! The object is already parsed.
If you have a string: Send it a `propertyList` message, which will parse the string as a property list and return whatever value is represented in it, which, in this case, will be a dictionary.